# creating a model structure in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I need to create a model having a structure like this:

```
name: 'xyz',
relatives: [ {name:'abc',age:'123'},{name:'def',age:'123'}..... ]
```

What i have is a loop which in each iteration generates data for relatives. And i have a model in this state like:

```
window.Persons.name='xyz'
```

**TWO QUESTIONS**

1. How to push relatives data in this model? I need to understand that how one can construct model instances having nested objects structures to any level?
2. I am setting the context of model to the window object so that its accessible in all the views as i collect data from different views. Like name is collected in some other view and relatives in some other view and this goes on....So am i doing the right thing? Or i am polluting the global namespace.

Please shed some light as i am sure i am lacking some fundamental understanding here.

Comment: Is this really a Backbone.js question? Do you have code you can share?

Comment: yes it is for backbone.js. The code just have lot of dependencies and i will need to put many functions to present it completely. Please see to what i exactly want to ask. I just need to know the way to form a json object representing my model. Hope this helps.