# jQuery: determine if a function was called as a jQuery event handler (callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a JavaScript function that can be called either directly, either as a callback from a jQuery event.

In the latter case, the jQuery Event object will be passed as an argument. When I call the function directly, I also provide an argument (of a different kind, but still an Object).

Therefore I need to be able to check (within the function body) how the function was invoked so as to know what sort of argument it's dealing with.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: can you provide your code whatever u have tried till now?

Comment: There's nothing very interesting with the code. What I tried simply is: when the function is called directly, I use a null value in first position and the useful argument in second position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accept the argument and then see if it's `instanceof` `jQuery.Event`:

```
function yourFunction(e) {
    if (e instanceof jQuery.Event) {
        // ...it was an event handler call
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/edehuw/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/edehuw/1/edit)

I would recommend avoiding this sort of thing, though. Instead, I'd recommend having the event handler *call* the target function (rather than using the target function as the actual event handler), if you need to distinguish the behavior depending on how it was called.

From your comment on the question:

> What I tried simply is: when the function is called directly, I use a null value in first position and the useful argument in second position.

In that case, it's even easier:

```
function yourFunction(e) {
    if (e) {
        // ...it was an event handler call -- or at least,
        // a non-falsey argument of some kind was passed in
    }
}
```

You don't even have to pass `null` into the function, just call it with no arguments. When you do that, `e` will be `undefined`, which is falsey. (The event object jQuery passes the handler will never be falsey.)

Comment: Thanks, your answer will be useful in my particular case. However I wonder: it doesn't seem very good practice, when designing a function, to presume that it won't be directly attached as an event handler.

Comment: @GlauberRocha: No, but you can expect (though probably not *assume*) that it will be called with the arguments you define for it. If you define it as taking no arguments (`function foo() { ... }`), then it doesn't matter whether something calls it with an argument or not (unless you look in the `arguments` object). The argument will just be completely ignored.

Answer (score -1):

try typeof() operator inside the if condition. if argument type comes out to be same, you may try assigning a unique property both the passing objects/events in either case and then perform a check agains that property...

Comment: `typeof` will just give you `"object"` in both cases

Comment: hm got it. can you do something with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852688/creating-a-model-structure-in-backbone :)

Comment: @beNerd I assume you see a relationship between my question and yours... but I'm sorry I don't. Leaving aside the fact that it hasn't been answered...