# forming nested objects

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

I need to create a JSON structure like this:

```
name: 'xyz',
relatives: [ {name:'abc',age:'123'},{name:'def',age:'123'}..... ]
```

At present i have this `window.Persons.name='xyz'`

I have a loop that gives me "relatives" attributes in each iteration. I need to do something like this:

```
window.Persons.items= //add some structure here
```

How should this be done? and whats the process to make it nested to any level if required.
My loop structure is this:

```
this.$('form').each(function(){
window.Persons.items= // add some structure here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the relatives information from your `form` somewhere, you can append the information to the relatives array

```
this.$('form').each(function(){
    var relative = $(this)....;
    window.Persons.relatives.push({ name: relative.name, age: relative.age });
}
```

if you want to collect multiple persons in an `items` array, you can append a person

```
window.Persons.items.push({ name: 'xyz', relatives: [] });
```

and append the relatives to this `relatives` array afterwards.

Comment: see my orignial question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852688/creating-a-model-structure-in-backbone Hope you get clear idea of what i exactly want.

Comment: @beNerd I just looked at your other (same?) question, but I don't really understand it. Do you want to collect data from multiple successive pages?